# Padding with adjustments on a Bootstrap 4 navbar menu system

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

New to Bootstrap 4 and making a dummy/mockup page with a header to get use to the `navbar` system.

I created [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dpsfwz5t/1/) (full code) here, but the gist of my page is:

**index.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitbythecron/bootstrap-troubleshooting/main/dummy-logo.png" class="img-fluid mainlogo" alt="Responsive image">
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navb">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navb">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:void(0)" id="aboutMenu" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          About
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:void(0)" id="fizzMenu" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Fizz
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:void(0)" id="buzzMenu" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Buzz
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:void(0)" id="foobarMenu" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Foobar
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:void(0)" id="resourcesMenu" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Resources
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:void(0)" id="helpMenu" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Help
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link red-button" href="javascript:void(0)">WATCH DEMO</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Sign In</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link bordered" href="javascript:void(0)">Sign Up</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**main.css**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Lato';
}

.bordered {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: #00142e;
}

.red-button {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #A81E30;
    background-color: #A81E30;
    color: beige;
}

.mainlogo {
    width: 35%;
}
```

When this runs I get:

[image]

The main problem here is the thickness of the padding around the navbar. How do I make it so that there is no padding, and that the height of the navbar is either the same as that of the logo and menu links, or at most just a pixel or two greater than? I **did** try adding `padding: 0px;` to the navbar style but that did not affect anything.

Also I would like to center **all** the navbar content (logo + menu items)...any ideas there? I did try adding `d-flex justify-content-center` to `navbar-collapse` but that also did nothing. Thanks in advance!

---

#### Update

I updated [my jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dpsfwz5t/2/) with the suggested changes from below and now I'm seeing:

[image]

So I'm still not seeing the navbar (again: logo + links) content centered and I'm seeing undesired padding, meaning the blue bar is a little too tall for what I'm looking for (I want something *shorter* and hugging the logo + links a little tighter).

Comment: Can you please show a graphic..... what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the centering, add `align-item: center` to your `unordered list`. That should be the child element of your `navbar-collapse` element, and it will center all your links vertically.

As for the padding, I think that it would be better to remove `class="img-fluid mainlogo" alt="Responsive image"` and instead just give your image a `height` property that you like. When I did just that, it also looked like it fixed your centering problem as well.

Let me know if that worked for you!

*edited to add code snippet*

```css
/*old selector for mainlogo*/
.mainlogo {
    width: 35%;
}

/*new selector for mainlogo*/
.mainlogo {
    height: 50px;
}

/*added selector. targets ul elements that are descendents of element with id "navb"*/
#navb ul {
  align-items: center;
}
```

[Navbar after changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4Zpa.png)

Comment: Thanks @MJPooler (+1) - **(1)** regarding the centering, I added `.navbar-nav { align-item: center; }` to my `main.css` but that did not change anything. And **(2)** I'm having a hard time visualizing what you're saying w.r.t. the `height` property for the padding part. Can you provide a simple code snippet with your answer to show me what you're talking about, for both? Thanks again so much!

Comment: Hello again! So, .navbar-nav is not the selector that you'll want to use, as the unordered list is the parent element that contains the child elements you want to center. #navb ul will target that ul, and the align-items: center will center the list items. 

For the second part of your question, it looks like your logo is set using a percentage, which will constantly change the size of your logo whenever the browser window is resized. I think that using a set height for the logo (or a set width) will solve your padding problems with the navbar and keep your logo a consistent size.

Comment: Thanks again @MJPoole (+1) -- please see my update which include a new link to an updated jsFiddle (which contains your suggested changes). I think we're headed in the right direction here, but still not quite getting the centering and de-padding that I'm looking for. Any other suggestions here? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I forked your work in JSFiddle, [see what I did](https://jsfiddle.net/Lyksunf3/7/).
In fact, I wrapped your `<nav>` whithin an `<header>`, then I have added the bootstrap class `container` to get the **content centered** depending on the screen size with `media-queries`.
Also, I have changed your content class `container-fluid` to `container` in order to have the same sizing results between the navbar and the rest of your page.
I removed the `img-fluid` on your image, in order to avoid stretching the image if the page is resized.

Also, as your question in an other post where I answered, I have changed the `navbar background` to fit your brand-logo background color ;)
And in **bonus** I added the class `navbar-dark`, now you can see your burger menu when nav items are collapse. Because [since bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#navbar) :

> .navbar-default is now .navbar-light, though .navbar-dark remains the same. One of these is required on each navbar. However, these classes no longer set background-colors; instead they essentially only affect color.

**Bonus 2 :** I removed your `red-button` class, and changed it to `btn btn-danger` which is quite the same, but with `hover` rules. And for your sign-up button, I added `btn btn-success`. I did that to let you learn on those classes too, because *it is not necessary to reinvent the wheel* :)

Then, you can use in your questions / answers in StackOverflow, the built-in JSFiddle `Javascript/HTML/CSS snippet CTRL-M` as below :

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Lato';
}

.bordered {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

header#nav-container{
  background-color: #001a31;
}


#navb ul {
    align-items: center;
}

.mainlogo {
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <title>Special Nonprofit</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='favicon.ico' />

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,300;1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  </head>
  <body>
  
  <header id="nav-container">
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitbythecron/bootstrap-troubleshooting/main/dummy-logo.png" class="mainlogo" alt="Responsive image">
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navb">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navb">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:void(0)" id="aboutMenu" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              About
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:void(0)" id="fizzMenu" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Fizz
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:void(0)" id="buzzMenu" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Buzz
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:void(0)" id="foobarMenu" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Foobar
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:void(0)" id="resourcesMenu" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Resources
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:void(0)" id="helpMenu" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Help
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link btn btn-danger" href="javascript:void(0)">WATCH DEMO</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Sign In</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link btn btn-success" href="javascript:void(0)">Sign Up</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
      <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
      <p>This is some text.</p>
    </div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This!

```css
 .sidebar { 
            height: 100%; 
            width: 0; 
            position: fixed; 
            /*Stays in place */ 
            background-color: #303630; 
            /*Grey*/ 
            overflow-x: hidden; 
      color:white;
      z-index: 12;
            /*for Disabling horizontal scroll */ 
        } 
        /* Position and style for the sidebar links */ 
        
        .sidebar a { 
            padding: 10px 10px 10px; 
            font-size: 25px; 
            color: #ffffff; 
            display: block; 
            transition: 0.3s; 
        } 
        /* the links change color when mouse hovers upon them*/ 
        
        .sidebar a:hover { 
            color: #ffffff; 
        } 
        /* Position and style the for cross button */ 
        
        .sidebar .closebtn { 
            position: absolute; 
            top: 0; 
            right: 25px; 
        } 
        /* Style for the sidebar button */ 
        
        .openbtn { 
            font-size: 25px; 
            background-color: #000000; 
            color: #ffffff; 
            padding: 10px 10px 10px; 
            border: none;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 12;
        } 
        /* the sidebar button changes 
    color when mouse hovers upon it */ 
.openbtn:hover { 
color: #FFFFFF; 
} 

    /* pushes the page content to the right 
    when you open the side navigation */ 
        
        #main { 
            transition: margin-left .5s; 
            /* If you want a transition effect */ 
            padding: 10px; 
        }
```

```html
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">
×
</a>

<a href="#">Placeholder 1</a>
<a href="#">Placeholder 2</a>
<a href="#">Placeholder 3</a>
<a href="#">Placeholder 4</a>
<a href="#">Placeholder 5</a>
<a href="#">Placeholder 6</a>
</div>
<div id="main">
<button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">
Hello
</button>

</div>
<script> 
    /* Sets the width of the sidebar 
    to 250 and the left margin of the 
    page content to 250 */ 
    function openNav() { 
        document.getElementById( 
        "sidebar").style.width = "250px"; 
        document.getElementById( 
        "main").style.marginLeft = "250px"; 
    } 

    /* Set the width of the sidebar 
    to 0 and the left margin of the 
    page content to 0 */ 
    function closeNav() { 
        document.getElementById( 
        "sidebar").style.width = "0"; 
        document.getElementById( 
        "main").style.marginLeft = "0"; 
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: This is from  W3Schools

Answer (score 0):

I have moved all the navbar content to the center with `mx-auto` class. removed the padding for top and bottom with `py-0` class. this equal to `padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0;` then with media queries. I'm switching between main and secondary logo.

Here's the code:

https://codepen.io/lachiweb/pen/dyXBGvd

Comment: @MJPoole Is this how you want the navbar to look?